# RecyclerView items not visible

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

RecyclerView  items not visible
I am  using a string array name item test and pass it to String array list, I used the same idea before and was working correctly

```
    listItemsTest = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(itemsTest));
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecycleViewTest);
    recycleViewAdapterTest = new RecycleViewAdapterTest(this,listItemsTest);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleViewAdapterTest);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

---

My Adapter

```
public class RecycleViewAdapterTest extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapterTest.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> ListTest;
Context context;

public RecycleViewAdapterTest(Context context, ArrayList<String> listTest) {

    this.ListTest = listTest;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecycleViewAdapterTest.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_list,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleViewAdapterTest.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ListTest.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    TextView textView;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLTest);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTest);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you need to set list value to viewholder's textview in **OnBindViewHolder**. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleViewAdapterTest.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String value = this.ListTest.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(value);// Try to make the textView public
}
```